# Pandas take mean only if a certain number of numerical values is present

Tags: python, pandas, mean

I have a dataset with triplicate values, like this:

```
ID  x   y   z
A   1   NA  NA
A   1   1   0.6
A   1   NA  0.4
B   NA  NA  NA
B   NA  0.5 1
B   NA  0.5 NA
...
```

I would like to take means of the triplicates for A and B, but only if there are two or more numerical values for each column and group. So the result should look like this:

```
ID  x   y   z
A   1   NA  0.5
B   NA  0.5 NA
```

Using `mean` with `groupby` results with taking all the column values. How to add a disclaimer that calculates mean only if a certain number of numerical values is present?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do `min_count` with `sum`, then divide with `count`. PS: interesting we do not have `min_count` in `mean`

```
s=df.groupby('ID').sum(min_count=2)/df.groupby('ID').count()
Out[178]: 
      x    y    z
ID               
A   1.0  NaN  0.5
B   NaN  0.5  NaN
```

Comment: perfect, thanks! seems like min_count would indeed be useful in mean

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution that might helps:

[image]

[image]